# Index of a subgroup containing a Sylow normalizer.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

The following is exercise $2.12$ in Paolo Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter $0$.

> Let $P$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and $H$ a subgroup containing $N_G(P)$. Then $p \mid |G:H|-1$.

I tried to use the fact that $H$ is self-normalizing, but could not see any relevance to this exercise. I also tried to imitate the trick which proved Sylow-III but failed.

Comment: The order of $\;H\;$ is divided by the order of $\;N_G(P)\;$ , but **the index** of this last group is the number $\;n_p\;$ of Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroups, and we know $\;n_p=1\pmod p\;$ , so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $P \subseteq N_G(P) \subseteq H$, so $N_H(P)=H \cap N_G(P)=N_G(P)$. Hence $n_p(H)=|H:N_H(P)|=|H:N_G(P)| \equiv 1$ mod $p$, by Sylow Theory in $H$. But $n_p(G)=|G:N_G(P)| \equiv 1$ mod $p$, by Sylow Theory in $G$. And one gets, $n_p(G)=|G:H|n_p(H)$. So ...

Answer (score 0):

1. $P\subseteq N_G(P)\subseteq H\subseteq G$ **[conditions]**
2. $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$ **[1]**
3. The number $n_p(H)$ of $p$-Sylow subgroups in $H$ is $[H:N_H(P)]$ **[Sylow-II]**
4. The number $n_p(G)$ of $p$-Sylow subgroups in $G$ is $[G:N_G(P)]$ **[Sylow-II]**
5. $N_H(P)=N_H(P)\cap H$ **[definition]**
6. $N_H(P)=N_G(P)$ **[1,5]**
7. $n_p(H)=[H:N_G(P)]$ **[3,6]**
8. $n_p(H)=1\text{ (mod }p) $ **[Sylow-III]**
9. $n_p(G)=1\text{ (mod }p) $ **[Sylow-III]**
10. $[H:N_G(P)]=1\text{ (mod }p) $ **[7,8]**
11. $[G:N_G(P)]=1\text{ (mod }p) $ **[4,9]**
12. $|H|/|N_G(P)|=pa+1$ **[10]**
13. $|G|/|N_G(P)|=pb+1$ **[11]**
14. $|G|/|H|=(pb+1)/(pa+1)=pc+d$ **[12,13]**
15. $(pc+d)(pa+1)=p^2ac+pc+pad+d=pb+1$ **[14]**
16. $(pc+d)(pa+1)=d\text{ (mod }p)$ **[15]**
17. $(pc+d)(pa+1)=1\text{ (mod }p)$ **[15]**
18. $d=1\text{ (mod }p)$ **[16,17]**
19. $|G|/|H|=1\text{ (mod }p)$ **[14,18]**
20. $[G:H]=1\text{ (mod }p)$ **[19]**